# Vectorize the distribution of a 2D matrix into a 3D matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 2D matrix `K` with shape (j, k) and I'd like to turn it into a 3D one `Q` by distributing the vectors according to another vector `d` (length i) which would match the new first dimension.

I have already done that with a loop, but the routine is called several times and the overall process takes too long:

```
def shift(self, arr, num, init):
   result = np.zeros((arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1]), dtype=np.int32)
   offset = num + init
   result[offset:,:] = arr[:-offset,:]
   return result

q = np.zeros((i, j, k), dtype=np.int32)
q[0,:,:] = K

for i in range(len(d)):
    q[:, i, :] = shift(q[:, i, :], int(d[i]))
```

Here basically I copy the initial matrix `K` into the first element of the first dimension of the 3D matrix `Q`, which is created with `np.zeros` and the final dimensions `(d.shape + K.shape)` and afterwards I'm "pushing" for each element in dimension 2 the number of positions in vector `d`.

Any ideas to avoid that for loop?

Comment: I'm a visual person, especially when thinking about "avoiding for loops".  I have to look at the big picture; visualize the action without getting lost in the details.  A small working example might help.  Are you doing anything with the last dimension?  Could you describe the same problem as one distributing a 1d into a 2d?  That may be easier to get an overview.

Comment: @jpaulj The same example could work distributing a 1d into a 2d: we have a vector `v = [4, 6, 3, 8]` to distribute and a vector `d = [9, 2, 3, 1]` (used to know how to distribute it) into a matrix `M` of shape 4x10, initialized in my example as `M = [[4, 6, 3, 8], [0, 0, 0, 0] ,[0, 0, 0, 0] ,[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0] ,[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0] ,[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0] ,[0, 0, 0, 0]]`. The desired output would be `M = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 8] ,[0, 6, 0, 0] ,[0, 0, 3, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0] ,[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0] ,[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0] ,[4, 0, 0, 0]]`.

Comment: in the 2d->3d case, is it conceptually correct to imagine the third dimension as a depth, and each row of `K` is pushed into that depth according to `d`?

Comment: BTW, your code is not working -- even after removing the argument `self` (since you give `shift()` outside of the class it was presumably initially written to).

Answer (score 0):

For the case in your comment:

```
In [853]: v = [4, 6, 3, 8]; d = [9, 2, 3, 1]
In [865]: q = np.zeros((10,4), int)
In [866]: q[d,np.arange(4)]=v
In [867]: q
Out[867]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 8],
       [0, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0]])
```